# How to hide title of any content type without using a module?

Tags: theming

I want to hide the title field of a particular content type (such as *Article*), but without using any modules.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why without a module? Modules are how you add/alter functionality in Drupal...

Comment: Is CSS an option?

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but--given that he wants to avoid modules, couldn’t he just create a template for the content type and remove the $title output from it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it in `template.php` in your theme dir, technically not a module.

e.g:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables){
  if ($variables['node']->type == 'article') {
    $variables['title'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Replace "MYTHEME" with your theme name and clear all caches at `Admin > Config > Performance` to apply.

Comment: Just as reference, although not requested by OP: Works in custom module as well: `MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$vars)`

Answer (score 4):

David is right, but if you want to use the $title elsewhere in the page you can use this approach.

Step 1. Create a show/hide title variable using hook_preprocess_page() in your custom module (or theme template.php, if you dont want to use a module):

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['show_title'] = TRUE; // so that showtitle is true by default
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
    if ($vars['node']->type == 'event') { // set to false when the content type is event
      $vars['show_title'] = FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

Where 'event' is the content type you want to hide the title for.

Step 2. Exclude the title in page.tpl.php by adding the show/hide title condition:

```
<?php if ($title && $show_title): ?>
  <h1><?php print $title; ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Clear the caches

Answer (score -1):

`node.tpl.php`: Check for `$type` before printing the `$title`
e.g. line #87 change to something like
if (!$page && $type != "your_type" ):

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal Answers. Could you please elaborate on your answer in order to improve it.